# Integrating Wordpress functions into Laravel as a Service Provider

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, service-provider

I am planning to use Laravel for the api of my Wordpress plugin. The structure is as below:

```
- main-directory
  - Laravel-dir
  - WordPress-dir
```

I have created a Wordpress Service Provider for Laravel as below:

```
use File;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class WordpressServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $bootstrapFilePath = '../../wp/wp-load.php';

    public function boot()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('app', '/app/public/app.css');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if(File::exists($this->bootstrapFilePath)) {
            require_once $this->bootstrapFilePath;
        } else throw new \RuntimeException('Wordpress Bootstrap File Not Found');
    }
}
```

I have also added it as a `provider =>` under `Laravel-dir/config/app.php`:

```
App\Providers\WordpressServiceProvider::class,
```

---

Now, when someone visits one of the Laravel pages, I need to check if the WordPress admin user is logged in.

**Skip to 'Edit' below**: I have tried `is_admin()` to check for the admin user. Calling the function works (doesn't complain), so I am assuming that my Service Provider works, but although I am logged in as wp-admin, `is_admin()` function always returns `false`.

---

**Edit:** *I realised `is_admin` is to check if the page is an admin page. Instead I had to use `wp_get_current_user()`*

I tried using `wp_get_current_user()` in my Wordpress plugin, and it returns all the admin's info. However, if I use it in Laravel, it returns empty sets of arrays.

Comment: _“However, if I use it in Laravel, it returns empty sets of arrays”_ – perhaps a cookie problem? Check what path the WP session cookie is set under, and if that covers the URL path that you call your Laravel thing under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into a similar problem myself. The issue was caused by the structure of my system.

I had laravel running on a subdomain whereas wordpress was running on the root domain. In such cases you do not have access to root domain cookies in the subdomain. In order to solve this I moved my laravel installation into a subdirectory of my webroot (where wordpress is installed) and created a rewrite rule for nginx to serve my laravel installation from www.yourdomain.com/laravel.

You need to edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com` and add for nginx to serve the laravel installation from yourdomain.com/laravel:

```
location ^~ /laravel {
    alias /pat/to/laravel/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location @laravel {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

If you are using apache take a look at [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score -1):

is_admin() is used to determine if you are on an admin page, not if you are an admin user.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Comment: You are right; I had to use `wp_get_current_user()` instead of `is_admin()`. **But**, when I use `wp_get_current_user()` in my Wordpress Plugin it returns the infos, however, if I try to use `wp_get_current_user()` in my Laravel app, it returns empty sets of arrays (even though the functions of WP became recognisable and doesn't crash or complain for function doesn't exist)

Comment: I would also like to achieve this and I got the same problem as senty. Could it be related to wordpress/laravel structute or the path/url that laravel is accessed from?